# How to plot 3D using NIntegrate

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I tried to plot the Mathematica of the code below but it repeatedly gave me an error...can you please help me out?

```
   In[1]:= h = 1

   Out[1]= 1

   In[2]:= b = Pi/(2 h)

   Out[2]= \[Pi]/2
  
   In[3]:= g[
    w_] := -(2 Sinh[b] Cosh[b])/(h [
    Sqrt[Cosh[Pi w/h] - 1][Sqrt[Cosh[Pi/h] - Cosh[Pi w/h]]]])

   In[4]:= r1[w_, x_, y_] := 
     Log (Cosh[(w - x) Pi/(2 h)] + 
        Sin[(h - y) Pi/(2 h)])/(Cosh[(w - x) Pi/(2 h)] - 
     Sin[(h - y) Pi/(2 h)])

     In[5]:= r2[w_, x_, y_] := 
      Log (Cosh[(w + x) Pi/(2 h)] + 
       Sin[(h - y) Pi/(2 h)])/(Cosh[(w + x) Pi/(2 h)] - 
       Sin[(h - y) Pi/(2 h)])
 
    In[6]:= u[x_, 
    y_?NumericQ] := (1/Pi) NIntegrate[
     g[w] (r1[w, x, y] - r2[w, x, y]), {w, 0, 1}]

     In[7]:= Plot3D[u[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 1}]

During evaluation of In[7]:= NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand -((2 Cosh[\[Pi]/2] (-((Log (1. +Cosh[1/2 \[Pi] (-1.99971+w)]))/(-1.+Cosh[1/2 \[Pi] Plus[<<2>>]]))+(Log (1. +Cosh[1/2 \[Pi] (1.99971 +w)]))/(-1.+Cosh[1/2 \[Pi] Plus[<<2>>]])) Sinh[\[Pi]/2])/1[Sqrt[-1+Cosh[\[Pi] w]][Sqrt[Cosh[\[Pi]]-Cosh[<<1>>]]]]) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}.
```

I tried to plot the Mathematica of the code below but it repeatedly gave me an error...can you please help me out?

Comment: Your brackets are all wrong here `-(2 Sinh[b] Cosh[b])/(h [
    Sqrt[Cosh[Pi w/h] - 1][Sqrt[Cosh[Pi/h] - Cosh[Pi w/h]]]])`. You are using square brackets `[]` where you should use parentheses `( )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had some syntax errors from your brackets which should be parentheses and also with `Log( ... )` which should be `Log[ ... ]`. The following works:

```
h = 1
b = Pi/(2 h)
g[w_?NumericQ] :=
 -(2 Sinh[b] Cosh[b])/(h (Sqrt[Cosh[Pi w/h] - 1] (Sqrt[Cosh[Pi/h] - Cosh[Pi w/h]])))

r1[w_, x_, y_] := 
 Log[Cosh[(w-x) Pi/(2 h)] + Sin[(h-y) Pi/(2 h)]]/(Cosh[(w-x) Pi/(2 h)] - Sin[(h-y) Pi/(2 h)])

r2[w_, x_, y_] := 
 Log[Cosh[(w+x) Pi/(2 h)] + Sin[(h-y) Pi/(2 h)]]/(Cosh[(w+x) Pi/(2 h)] - Sin[(h-y) Pi/(2 h)])

u[x_, y_?NumericQ] := (1/Pi) NIntegrate[g[w] (r1[w,x,y] - r2[w,x,y]), {w,0,1}]
Plot3D[u[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: https://imgur.com/0dZWCkR    Thank you very much for your effort. the link attached is the actual Mathematica plot that I want to obtain...it was in page 186 of Book (Mixed boundary value problem by Dean g Duffy)...can you please help me once more with the Mathematica code to achieve it!?    Thank you.

Comment: Something in your equations is wrong because if I add `PlotRange->{{-2,2},{0,1},{-3/2,3/2}}` and `Exclusions->None` to the `Plot`, I still have the singularities and it doesn't look like your image. Check your equations and fix the syntax errors like I have done above.